# Is there a way to force locale on a given spring message?

Tags: spring, locale, message

```
<spring:message code="someMessageCode" />
```

This works with the user locale (browser locale). I have a need to force locale on a particular message. I can handle this with a scriplet but I was wondering if there is a way we can tell Spring to use a specific locale for a particular messsage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is possible with spring messages macro, but you can create a `MessageSourceAccessor` and use it.

Ex:

```
MessageSourceAccessor messageResolver = new MessageSourceAccessor(messageSource, locale);
```

Pass it to freemarker, then in freemarker

```
${messageResolver.getMessage("someMessageCode")}
```

Comment: I got MessageSourceAccessor to do what I need. Thanks!